# avoid twice unregister form service android

Tags: java, android, android-service

Can I do like that:

```
mBoradcastReciver = null;
void register(){
  if(mBoradcastReciver == null){
     mBoradcastReciver = new ...
     registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, ....);
  }
}

void unregister(){
    if(mBoradcastReciver != null){
       unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
       mBoradcastReciver = null;
    }
```

and method register() and unregister() call every time I want? 
Is any potential problems with that approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Potential problem is that if the receiver is not null and not registered you will get an `IllegalStateException`. So either make a boolean flag or `catch` the exception. The boolean flag would be set to `true` when you register the receiver and then you set to `false` when you unregister.

Comment: @user1461568 Threading can always cause problems. You should probably [make the methods `synchronized`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) to avoid issues if you *are* [going to multithread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/).

Comment: @user1461568 if my answer helped, you may want to accept the answer. If you have other *related* questions, feel free ask!